# Validation loss is constant and training loss decreasing

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, trainingloss

I have a model training and I got this plot. It is over audio (about 70K of around 5-10s) and no augmentation is being done. I have tried the following to avoid overfitting:

- Reduce complexity of the model by reducing number of GRU cells and hidden dimensions.
- Add dropout in each layer.
- I have tried with higher dataset.

What I am not sure is if my calculation of training loss and validation loss is correct. It is something like this. I am using drop_last=True and I am using the CTC loss criterion.

```
train_data_len = len(train_loader.dataset)
valid_data_len = len(valid_loader.dataset)
epoch_train_loss = 0
epoch_val_loss = 0
train_losses = []
valid_losses = []

    model.train()
    for e in range(n_epochs):
        t0 = time.time()
        #batch loop
        running_loss = 0.0
        for batch_idx, _data in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
            # Calculate output ...
             # bla bla
            loss = criterion(output, labels.float(), input_lengths, label_lengths)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()
            # loss stats
            running_loss += loss.item() * specs.size(0)
                
        t_t = time.time() - t0

            
        ######################    
        # validate the model #
        ######################
        with torch.no_grad():
            model.eval() 
            tv = time.time()
            running_val_loss = 0.0
            for batch_idx_v, _data in enumerate(valid_loader, 1):
                #bla, bla
                val_loss = criterion(output, labels.float(), input_lengths, label_lengths)
                running_val_loss += val_loss.item() * specs.size(0)
        
            print("Epoch {}: Training took {:.2f} [s]\tValidation took: {:.2f} [s]\n".format(e+1, t_t, time.time() - tv))
                
                
        epoch_train_loss = running_loss / train_data_len
        epoch_val_loss = running_val_loss / valid_data_len
        train_losses.append(epoch_train_loss)
        valid_losses.append(epoch_val_loss)
        print('Epoch: {} Losses\tTraining Loss: {:.6f}\tValidation Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
                e+1, epoch_train_loss, epoch_val_loss))
        model.train()
```

[image]

Comment: check if you missed `optimizer.zero_grad()` in the training loop.

Comment: no, I didn't miss it, otherwise, the training loss wouldn't reduce I think in that case.....I omitted it to make it simpler.

Comment: which loss_criterion are you using? The way you are using train_data_len and valid_data_len is wrong, unless you are using `drop_last =True` in the DataLoader

In this case you have to use len(batch_size) as train_data_len and valid_data_len

Comment: Yes, I am using drop_last = True, otherwise when the length didn't match the batch size, it would have given me error. criterion = nn.CTCLoss(blank=28, zero_infinity=True)

Comment: Okay, but the batch_size is not equal to len(train_loader.dataset) How big is your batch_size and print out len(train_loader.dataset) and give me that information too

Comment: No, it is not but after the whole iteration, in total it will be for the total length of the train_loader, no?
Batch_size=32 and train_loader size = 71858

Comment: Well I usually see people use `valid_size += batch_size` in each iteration then you can also put `drop_last=False` I cant see an error how you use the Loss, your model with all the training you deliever seem to be completly trained out. If you use early stopping how long does it train?

Comment: I am thinking that may be because I am using layer normalization, the training losses drops too faster...I am trying the model again without layer normalization to check.